# How make "typeof" on extends in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Example:

```
class Foo extends Bar {

}

Foo typeof Bar //-> false :(
```

How discover that `Foo` extend `Bar`?

Comment: you need `instanceof` not `typeof`

Answer (score 3):

As ES6 classes inherit prototypically from each other, you can use [`isPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/isPrototypeOf)

```
Bar.isPrototypeOf(Foo) // true
```

Alternatively just go with the usual [`instanceof` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof):

```
Foo.prototype instanceof Bar // true
// which is more or (in ES6) less equivalent to
Bar.prototype.isPrototypeOf(Foo.prototype)
```

Answer (score 1):

MDN for `typeof` :

> The typeof operator returns a string indicating the type of the
>   unevaluated operand

you need `instanceof`, `isPrototypeOf`

```
class Bar{}
class Foo extends Bar {}
var n  = new Foo();

console.log(n instanceof Bar); // true
console.log(Bar.isPrototypeOf(Foo)); // true
console.log(Foo.prototype instanceof Bar); // true
```

Comment: This requires creating an instance, which can have undesired side-effects. I think he wants to do it from the functions themselves.