# why `Element instanceof Node` return false

Tags: javascript, dom, element

I don't know why `Element instanceof Node` return false, since any element , whose nodeType is 1, is a special type of Node.

The following is what I found from MDN :

> The following interfaces all inherit from Node its methods and properties: Document, Element, CharacterData (which Text, Comment, and CDATASection inherit), ProcessingInstruction, DocumentFragment, DocumentType, Notation, Entity, EntityReference

And question 2: why any element in DOM is both the instanceof Element and the instanceof Node.The code is below:

```
var div = document.querySelector("div");
div instanceof Node;//true
div instanceof Element;//true
Element instancof Node;//false
```

Comment: Because `instanceof` tests if something is an **instance** of something. `Element` is not an instance. It's a constructor.

Comment: `Element instanceof Function` would be true. To check whether classes inherit from each other, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35921495/1048572)

Comment: Note that browsers don't necessarily have to implement prototype inheritance.

Comment: Clarification, `Element` is *an* instance, an instance of a `Function`, though it is not an instance of a `Node`.

Comment: @RobG, not sure what you're referring to there. Browsers don't necessarily have to implement ECMAScript at all, but compatibility tends to be in their best interest. Is there a specific part of prototypical inheritance that is optional that you're referring to?

Comment: I know finally, Element.prototype instanceof Node.Thanks you all though somebody minus my point (ㄒoㄒ)/~~

Comment: @zzzzBov—I'm referring to host objects. Browsers don't have to implement DOM elements using prototype inheritance, or an *Element* object at all (e.g. IE up to version 7 didn't).

Comment: @RobG, host object support is drastically different from "prototype inheritance" in general

Comment: @zzzzBov—Element (if it exists) is a host object, as are all DOM objects. That's my point.

Comment: @zzzzBov "host object support is drastically different from "prototype inheritance" in general" can you put it in details, I am curious about it~

Comment: @RobG I'm not disagreeing with that, but your first comment made it sound like browsers were forgoing prototypal inheritance entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Element` is a `Function` because it's a constructor.

`Element.prototype` is a `Node`.

> since any element , whose nodeType is 1, is a special type of Node.

Notice that `Element.nodeType` is `undefined`, as `Element` isn't a `Node`.

> Why are elements in the DOM both instances of Element and Node?

The prototype chain allows us to essentially define classes and extend defined classes.

```
function Foo() {...}
```

creates what can be considered a class of `Foo`

```
function Bar() {...}
```

creates what can be considered a class of `Bar`

```
Foo.prototype = new Bar(...);
```

creates a relationship where `Foo` extends `Bar`.

Using this code, if you create a `Foo` instance:

```
var f = new Foo();
```

`f` is an instance of `Foo`, *and* an instance of `Bar`.

The same hierarchy applies to `Element` and `Node`, where `Element` extends `Node`.

Comment: The DOM standard describes a series of interfaces (e.g. [interface **Node**](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#node) that are implemented in modern browsers using constructors and prototype inheritance consistent with ECMAScript. However, the interfaces *can* be implemented in other ways and have been in the past, even where the host supports javascript (e.g. IE up to version 7 at least), so there may not be a global *Element* object. ;-)